# Problems updating field in object subarray mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have some problems with updating an field in my mongoose model.
I'm trying to find a username in a list of friends in a user model and then update a field in that same object that has the username.

This is how I've done, but status won't update:

```
router.post('/profile/:id/friendRequest/:username', authenticateUser)
router.post('/profile/:id/friendRequest/:username', async (req, res) => {
  const { id, username } = req.params;
  const { status } = req.query;

  try {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id, 'friends.username': username},  {$set: 
    {'friends.$.status': status}}, {new:true, upsert: true}).exec();
  
      res.json({
        friends: user.friends,
        success: true,
        loggedOut: false,
      })
    } catch (err) {
      catchError(res, err, 'Invalid user id');
    }
});
```

The part of my schema I'm trying to update status in:

```
User({
    friends: {
    status: Number,
    username: String,
    state: String
  }
});
```

Would love some help to get me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) documentation,you can use "friends.status" in the second argument.
"friends.$.status" will look for the status property within the $ property of friends.

Comment: I've tried this before, and all I get is "bad request" when I do that...